# How to get the object(file) expiration date from boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a file inside the AWS S3 bucket like below format.

```
/bucket_name/prefix1/prefix3/file_name.txt
```

I am trying to get the expiration date for file_name.txt object, but I am getting only Prefix level expiration date.

How to get the expiration date for file(object level)??

I have tried the below code

```
bucket        = "bucket_name"
prefix        = "/prefix1/prefix3/"
key           = "file_name.txt"
s3            = boto3.client('s3')
policy_data_1 = s3.get_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(Bucket=bucket)
bucket_policy = policy_exists_1['Rules'][0]['Expiration']
print(bucket_policy, policy_exists['Rules'])
```

I am getting below output

```
'Rules': [{'Expiration': {'Days': 6}, 'ID': 'S3 Object Prefix Expiration Rule for bucket_name/prefix1/prefix2/', 'Prefix': 'prefix1/prefix2/', 'Status': 'Enabled', 'NoncurrentVersionExpiration': {'NoncurrentDays': 6}, 'AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload': {'DaysAfterInitiation': 7}}, {'Expiration': {'Days': 6}, 'ID': 'S3 Object Prefix Expiration Rule for 'bucket_name/prefix1/prefix3/', 'Prefix': 'prefix1/prefix3/', 'Status': 'Enabled', 'NoncurrentVersionExpiration': {'NoncurrentDays': 6}, 'AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload': {'DaysAfterInitiation': 7}}
]
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate since he wants to get the expertion date with boto3 and not with Java SDK.

Comment: @johnBatts Here I am trying to get the expiration date by using boto3, not adding the life cycle policies.

Comment: Can you please upload the properties of the file? https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ThpB.png

Comment: @johnBatts I am looking for Object level expiry not the bucket level, Please read the question before answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong call

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('bucket-name', 'filename.txt')
print (object.expiration)
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object